# How i can deploy an Azure Function needed for an SPFx web part

Tags: development, spfx, azure-functions

I want to install the `react-chatgpt-app` SPFx from https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-chatgpt-app . and as part of the prerequisites is that we need to install an azure function, now i unzip the azure function folder where i got those :-

[image]

[image]

so how i can deploy this azure function to azure function app? the documentation mentioned the following:-

> In the directory ./OpenAIFunctionProject/OpenAI-azure-functions.zip
> you will found the project with AzureFunction zip.ed, please copy to
> local computer unzip and deploy. The Azure Function App needs to be
> configured with Authentication Provider Microsoft , please see the
> README.md file on the project.

also the readme mentioend the following:-

> To deploy you can use the Azure Extensions for VSCODE , go to
> "WORKSPACE" and on top Options select Deploy.

so what that mean exactly? any advice on how i can deploy this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to unzip the file. Azure supports deployment of Azure functions using zip file and you can use Azure CLI

Azure CLI can be used from azure portal or can be installed in the system.

Azure CLI command for azure function zip deployment :

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --src <SrcOfYourAzureFunction.zip> --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourFunctionAppName>
```

Ref: [Zip deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push)